# increasing the battery amps to fit a water pump

Tags: voltage, amperage

I have a battery of 12V(yuasa YB3L-B), 0.036 Ampere, and a water pump(SEAFLO bilge pump), running on 12V, 1.8 Ampere. How can I increase the amps of the battery to fit with the pump?

Comment: Don't know where you got that 0.036A spec from ... That battery should run your pump quite happily for an hour or so.

Comment: You don't 'increase the amps of the battery to fit the pump'. You provide a power supply of the correct voltage and of adequate current rating (amps) to run the pump _at maximum load_. The pump will draw whatever current it requires, increasing with increasing load.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know where you got the 0.036A number for the Yuasa YB3L-B battery. Batteries of that type and their equivalent replacements are rated for 3 Amp Hour.

With a fully charged fresh battery you should be able to easily run the bilge pump for an hour or more as the pump drawing 1.8A is less than Amp Hour rating of the battery.

If your battery is only delivering 0.036A then it is either not connected to the load correctly or the battery is completely kaput and needs replacement with a new one.